# windows 10 raises error while I am not using the laptop

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, error-logging

I bought a new laptop with Windows 8.1 and I have upgrade it directly to Windows 10 pro (I use it under Windows 8.1 just during the update process). From then, while it is on but I am not using it, an error occurs. I did not manged to catch what the error message is. Just once, I could see that the light blue screen is showing and I reached it after it was restarted.

- Is that a know issue?
- Can I find the error message logged somewhere?

Laptop: Dell Precision 7710

Comment: Look in the event logs.

Comment: For BSOD errors, you can find them in event viewer, or you can read them by downloading the program [bluescreenview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html). You could also upload the .dmp files to a cloud based sharing for someone to download and analyze using WinDbg.